# d3js, rotate element from their center

Tags: rotation, d3.js, translation, transform

I'm trying to make a function which orient elements to a clicked one.
The code works (orient angle is good) but there is a translation before the rotation to place the element at good place and make the rotation according to their center.

Sorry if my code is bad, i'm not good in Math and i used some tutorial in order to make it work.
The function take the element to orient and his offset position in his container.

```
function refresh(scot, offSetX, offSetY){
        // récupére et traite l'id
        var id = scot.attr("id")
        var sid = id.substring(0, id.length-6);
        // dimensions et positions scot courant (curent element to orient)
        var w1 = _scotDim[sid+"Points"][0]/2;
        var h1 = _scotDim[sid+"Points"][1]/2;
        var x1 = _initPos[sid+"Points"][0];
        var y1 = _initPos[sid+"Points"][1];
        var x1prim = _initPos[sid+"Points"][0]+offSetX;
        var y1prim = _initPos[sid+"Points"][1]+offSetY;
        // dimensions et positions du scot vers lequel se tourner (target element to focus)
        var w2 = _scotDim[dadID+"Points"][0]/2;
        var h2 = _scotDim[dadID+"Points"][1]/2;
        var x2 = _initPos[dadID+"Points"][0];
        var y2 = _initPos[dadID+"Points"][1];
        var x2prim = _initPos[dadID+"Points"][0]+offSetX;
        var y2prim = _initPos[dadID+"Points"][1]+offSetY;
        // calcul de la différence entre les positions du scot courant et du scot vers lequel se tourner
        var p1x = x1+w1+_offSetX;// position du scot courant
        var p1y = y1+h1+_offSetY;
        var p2x = x2+w2+_offSetX;// position du scot vers lequel s'orienter
        var p2y = y2+h2+_offSetY;
        // calcul de l'orientation à appliquer sur le scot courant
        var p1xprim = x1prim+w1;
        var p1yprim = y1prim+h1;
        var p2xprim = x2prim+w2;
        var p2yprim = y2prim+h2;
        var deltax = p2xprim - p1xprim;
        var deltay = p2yprim - p1yprim;
        // valeur de la rotation à appliquer
        var anglInDegrees = Math.atan2(deltay, deltax) * 180 / Math.PI;
        //console.log(sid+" : Orientation>>"+anglInDegrees+" // Position x/y>>"+p1x+"/"+p1y);
        // animation du scot courant (translation et rotation)
        d3.select("#"+sid+"Bulle").transition().duration(320)
            .attr("transform", function(){
                return "translate("+offSetX+", "+offSetY+") rotate("+anglInDegrees+", "+p1x+", "+p1y+")";
            })
            .delay(50).style("opacity", 1);

        // fait disparaitre la bulle du scot cliqué
        if(dadID+"Points" == id){
            d3.select("#"+sid+"Bulle").transition().duration(400)
                .style("opacity", 0);
        }
    }
```

It's this line:

```
d3.select("#"+sid+"Bulle").transition().duration(320)
            .attr("transform", function(){
                return "translate("+offSetX+", "+offSetY+") rotate("+anglInDegrees+", "+p1x+", "+p1y+")";
```

which make the transformation, rest of code is good. It's juste the succession of translation/rotation which dont make the effect that i want. 
**At each click we can see a little transition before the rotation (in theorie this translation juste place elements in order to make the rotation according to their center)**

You can see the actual result here: http://www.pixelreseller.com/d3giro/
Click on the circle map to launch animation.

ps: sorry if my langage is bad. And ask for adding information.

Comment: It looks like you only want to change the value for `rotate`. Why are you changing the ones for `translate` as well?

Comment: Yep, i only want to rotate my element, but if i remove the translate, elements stay at their origin position. This method is called for each element (5 elements) and offSetX/offSetY represent the offset position relative to container position.

Comment: If i remove the translate, elements stay at their origin position and the little translate effect before rotate continues. I think i'm not rotating exactly by elements center ..

Comment: You could remove the requirement to have a translate in there by putting the objects into a group and then translating that.

Comment: Done with css3 instead of pure javascript